# If-Statement going crazy (or me?)

Tags: bash

This is one of my parameters of my bash script. But it seems that there's something going wrong.

Bash script:

```
case "${1}" in
--api )
        if ( "${2}" == "US" ); then
            sparkEndpoint="https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions"
            shift
        elif ( "${2}" == "EU" ); then
            sparkEndpoint="https://api.eu.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions"
            shift
        else
            echo -e ${parameterNotSpecified}
            echo -e ${usageApi}
            break
        fi
        shift
    ;; [...]
```

Console output:

```
./fn_sendmail.sh --api EU
./fn_sendmail.sh: Zeile 95: EU: Kommando nicht gefunden.
./fn_sendmail.sh: Zeile 98: EU: Kommando nicht gefunden.
You called an option but didn't specified it! Usage of --api
--api [eu,us]
        Description: Sets the API endpoint for Sparkpost
        Necessary: No
        Default: EU
```

Comment: Use [] instead of ()

Comment: @MrTux ty, that helped for the './fn_sendmail.sh: Zeile 98: EU: Kommando nicht gefunden.'s But no matter if using double or single quotes, US / EU are not accepted and the script calls my "else"

Comment: Further explanation: `( )` tries to run its contents in a subshell, so when `$2` is "EU",`( "${2}" == "US" )` creates a subshell that tries to run the command `EU` with arguments "==" and "US". `[ ]`, on the other hand, tries to parse its contents as a test expression, which is what you want. If it's still not working, use `=` instead of `==`. If *that* doesn't work, put `set -x` before it, and it'll show exactly what's getting executed, giving a better idea what's going wrong.

Comment: @GordonDavisson ty for the explanation, this was very useful for the understanding of what's going. In the end [] + "" + = was the solution.

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` doesn't work consistently between different versions of `echo` -- I once had an OS upgrade break a bunch of my scripts for a similar reason (`echo -n` in my case). I'd recommend including literal newlines in your strings, and then putting double-quotes around the variable references so they don't get mangled.[shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like unquoted variable references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use [] instead of ()

2) Use = instead of ==

See the comment of @GordonDavisson to understand why

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to

```
shift 2
```

to remove both the `--api` **and** the location (US/EU).